# Can't access my External WD Passport HDD B/C of a checksum error

Tags: mount, external-hdd

**Background info:** 
I have a mid 2012 13" macbook pro running Mavericks that started to have HDD slow downs. As a precaution, I backed up my user data to a 2TB western digital "my passport" hard drive (formatted in exFAT). A couple days after performing this backup, my macbook pro died. Note: I did not use time machine, I just saved my data from the users folder.

After my macbook pro died, I started using a temporary laptop that is running Ubuntu 14.04. I had successfully mounted the "passport" drive just days ago to retrieve a file and everything worked fine.

**Problem:** 
But today, when I finally had time to properly reduplicate the user data from the "passport" drive to another backup drive... of course, the passport drive is no longer mounting. It gives me the following error message:

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/rbuse/My Passport:
>   Command-linemount -t "exfat" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,io
>   charset=utf8,namecase=0,e rrors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1"
>   "/media/rbuse/My Passport"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
>   stdout:FUSE exfat 1.0.1
>
> ' stderr: ERROR:._.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent' has invalid
>   checksum (0x6634 != 0x4044). '

Note that I can see the passport drive listed in the Devices section of Files. But when I click on it, it pops up a window with the above error message.

**What can I do to get it to mount properly?**

Comment: Plug it into a windows machine and run chkdsk/scandisk on it?

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168832 - nice discussion, hope it helps